# Powershell where-object complex logic

Tags: powershell, where-clause

I am having trouble coming up with a way to do complex logic using the where-object in PowerShell

I have the following code, but separating the and from the ors is not working as intended.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {($_.Enabled) -and
                                    (($_.DistinguishedName -Contains "world") -or
                                        ($_.DistinguishedName -Contains "foo")) -and
                                        (($_.SID -Contains "bar") -or
                                        ($_.SID-Contains "something else"))}
```

If I do this in c# I get results, but in powershell I do not.

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

TIA

Comment: what happens if you add one test at a time? at what point does the test fail to give the expected results?

Comment: Why would the `SID` contain strings?

Comment: also, the `-contains` operator is a _collection_ operator, not a string operator. you likely otta use either `-match` or `-like` with wildcards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would perform your query using AD PS Module:

```
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"|where-object{
    $_.DistinguishedName -match 'World|Foo' -and $_.SID -match 'bar|something else'
}
```

- `-LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"` = Enabled Computer Object
- `-match` allows the use of regex, you can use the pipeline as `OR`.

`-contains` is the operator you would use to lookup an item on an array. Example:

```
PS /> @(
'apple'
'banana'
'pineapple'
) -contains 'apple'

True
```

In addition, as Dave Wyatt pointed out in a nice post on powershell.org a while ago, you might want to avoid `where-object` whenever possible since it's the slowest way to filter collections. It's only advantages are the low memory consumption and pipeline streaming.
Here are a few examples of faster efficient code:

```
#Example 1:
$computers=Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
$collection=[system.collections.generic.list[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer]]::new()

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    if($computer.DistinguishedName -match 'World|Foo' -and $computer.SID -match 'bar|something else')
    {
        $collection.add($computer)
    }
}

#Example 2:
filter myFilter{
    if($_.DistinguishedName -match 'World|Foo' -and $_.SID -match 'bar|something else')
    {
        $_
    }
}

$computers=Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"|myFilter

#Example 3
$computers=(Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)").where({
    $_.DistinguishedName -match 'World|Foo' -and $_.SID -match 'bar|something else'  
})
```

There is plenty on information on the different ways of filtering Collections on PowerShell and their pros / cons on Google.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the knowledge sharing I needed. I appreciate every ones input and sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

<s>***this is not an Answer - so please let me know when you have read it so that i can delete it.***</s>

this is your code with more informative indentation, with the needless extra parens removed, and with spaces around the operators.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Enabled -and
        ($_.DistinguishedName -Contains "world" -or
            $_.DistinguishedName -Contains "foo") -and
        ($_.SID -Contains "bar" -or
            $_.SID -Contains "something else")
        }
```

note that the `-contains` operator is NOT for strings ... it is for membership in a collection. if you want to test against strings, use `-match`, or `.Contains()`, or `-like` with wildcards.

Comment: "the `-contains` operator is NOT for strings" - kinda sounds like an answer Lee ;-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - ok ... i will remove that part of the Answer. thank you for the feedback! [*grin*]

Comment: Why not just remove the disclaimer? Why do you hate answering questions so much? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - many times the Answer feels more like a comment to me. i seem to have a bit of a problem deciding what side of the line this one otta be on.

Comment: Read, Thank you very much.

Comment: @john - you are most welcome! glad to help ... and i will leave the Answer since MathiasR.Jessen seems to think it makes the grade as such. [*grin*]